# Reading a dat file in C

Tags: c, fread

I would like to know if it's possible to read a dat file that I didn't create.
As far as I know the `fread` function requires a struct record but since I didn't create this dat file I can't know which fields the record has.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not know the file structure and format how can you honestly expect to read it in a coherent manner?

Comment: `.dat` is about the most vague possible file extension. There are literally *thousands* of different formats, documented and undocumented, that you could be dealing with here -- without knowing which one you've got, we can't possibly answer.

Comment: "knowing which one you've got, we can't possibly answer" here is a link to the file http://www.fileconvoy.com/index.php?Section=6 but I think I got an answer, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is dat file? Yes, you can read binary file, and it looks like you understand it.

But since your goal is not to just read file, but "parse" it, you need to be familiar with its structure to know where to look for a data, and apparently you are not familiar with file's structure.

Comment: a file that ends with ".dat", binary. since it's not a plain text I can't really read that so it's imposible I guess right?

Comment: no, you can read even binary file. there is no differences between text and binary files, since text is basically just a representation of binary data. you "can not" read it because it's impossible for you to parse data until you know where to look for it - know the file structure.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possible. [Reading the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) reveals that `fread` simply requires a pointer to some memory into which it attempts to read data, and it returns the number of bytes it succeeded to read.

Make sure to open the file in binary mode.

For example:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("somefile.dat", "rb");

char buf[10];

size_t n = fread(buf, 10, 1, fp);

if (n > 0)
{
    /* we succeeded at reading n bytes,
     * which are now in buf[i] for i in [0, n)
     */
}
```

In real code you would typically either read individual pieces as dictated by your serialization format, or if you want to read the entire file content, you'd have a loop:

```
char buf[4096];

for (size_t n; (n = fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, fp)) != 0; )
{
    /* process buf[i] for i in [0, n). For example: */

    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        printf("0x02X ", (unsigned char)(buf[i]));
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error "argument of type char is incompatible with parameter of type "void"

Comment: @ImriPersiado: I doubt that. What exactly are you calling?

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake in my code, but I don't understand what to do after the if statement. you already read the bytes why do you want keep reading n bytes?

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Sorry! "read" is in the past tense, as in "we just succeeded at reading `n` bytes". That's not very clear in English, apologies. I'll rephrase it.

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Real code would of course run this in a loop, such as `for (size_t n; (n = fread(...)) != 0); ) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I understand everything except this line "/* process buf[i] for i in [0, n) */" what are you trying to do in here? and what is this format [0, n) ? i'm an amateur c programmer sorry for that.

Comment: Ok it can read it now but what I get is binary of course and not plain text, struct.

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Well, just do with the file contents whatever you want. I added an example (printing a hex dump).